# How to more efficiently reshape my dataframe into a new form (R)?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, reshape2, melt

I have a dataset like this (`df1`)

```
ID  2   4   6   8   10  12  14  16  18  20  22  24   Day
1   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   1   0   1   0    Sunday
1   0   0   0   0   0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   Monday
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   Tuesday
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   Wednesday
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   Thursday
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   Friday
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   Saturday
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   Sunday
2   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   Monday
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   Tuesday
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   Wednesday
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   Thursday
2   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   1   0   0   Friday
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   Saturday
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   Sunday
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   Monday
3   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   2   0   0   0   Tuesday
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   Wednesday
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   Thursday
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   Friday
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   Saturday
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   Sunday
```

and I have an `ID` checklist like this:

```
ID
1
2
3
```

I want to convert the `df1` into this kind of output:

```
ID  Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4    Var5 ...... Var82   Var83 Var84
1   0         0      0         0     2             2      0     0
2
3
```

where `Var1` represents 'Sunday 2' (in the first dataframe) and var84 represents the 'Saturday24'. I want to export my result as a `.csv` file.

I am doing this by using a for loop (shown below) because there are too many ID's. However, the problem is these codes are running very slowly. Is there any faster way to get the same result?

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
for (i in ID_checklist$ID) {

  x= filter(df1$ID %in% i)
  x$Day = NULL
  df.melted = melt(t(x[,-1]), id.vars = NULL)
  myNewDF = data.frame(i, t(df.melted[,3]))
  write.table(myNewDF,file="my12x7.csv", append=TRUE,sep=",",col.names=FALSE,row.names=FALSE)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
library(reshape2)

# this may be unnecessary depending on your data
# it will make sure the weekday columns come in the same order
# as the weekdays appear in your original data
df1$Day = factor(df1$Day, levels = unique(df1$Day))

# convert to a fully long format
df_long = melt(df1, id.var = c("ID", "Day"))

# convert to the wide format you want
result = dcast(data = df_long, ID ~ Day + variable, fun.aggregate = sum)
```

This will append the day names with the current variable. If you'd rather have them as `Var1 Var2 Var3`, use `paste()` and rename the columns.

We can look at the first few columns to verify:

```
result[, 1:6]
#   ID Sunday_X2 Sunday_X4 Sunday_X6 Sunday_X8 Sunday_X10
# 1  1         0         0         0         0          2
# 2  2         0         0         0         0          0
# 3  3         0         0         0         0          0
```